# Column is constrained to be unique, Value is already present

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am trying to create simple form using C# which display information from the SQL database for users just to view some informations, i used the primary key field as a drop-down Item but i kept getting this error, What did i miss?

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.ConstraintException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Column 'itemId' is constrained to be unique. 
>   Value '100202' is already present.

[image: Image added]

Comment: Can you please add snippet of your code as well? You are adding items twice.

Comment: @Prajwal i used binding source Drag and drop, i added image, I am a newbee to C# where can i get the generated code when i use drag and drop options

Comment: Show me how you are retrieving the data from Db.

Comment: This means you are trying to insert a new item with the same id -- you are doing one of two things -- 1) you really want to update but you are inserting, 2) you don't want to have a value passed in for the id column on your insert statement.

Comment: @Hogan i dont want to insert or update i would rather use the id field for users to retrieve data from the Database JUST VIEW. If they update or insert will create will be a mess, i dont want that to happen. Is there anyways to block insert or update?

Comment: When do you get this error. On start of the application? On selecting a value?

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen On selecting a value

Comment: Please check, that the "IsEditable" property of the combobox is set to false.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen i cant find "IsEditable" Nor "isReadOnly" property but that is what i am looking

Comment: Sorry, its WinForms, not WPF. Change property of the combobox  "DropDownStyle" to "DropDownList". To be sure to prevent any changing and also show this the user, you could remove the "Add", "Delete" and "Save" buttons from the binding navigator.